# Establish if a continuous sequence exists within tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to establish if a continuous sequence exists within a tuple.

For example, I wish to return `True` in this case:

```
is_sequence_within((1,2), (1,2,3))
```

and `False` in this case:

```
is_sequence_within((1,3), (1,2,3))
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "subset" here; there are no sets, and `{1,3}.issubset({1,2,3})` gives `True`.  Do you mean "contiguous subsequence"?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: It's not a subset. It's finding if one sequence of elements is contained in the other.

Comment: @DSM Renamed question.

Comment: @Lutz Horn I don't intend on reinventing the wheel if such a function is already available within a library.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this is something that `itertools` will handle more elegantly, but....

```
def is_sequence_within(seq, target):
    for i in range(len(target)-len(seq)+1):
        if seq == target[i:i+len(seq)]: return True
    return False
```

Alternatively:

```
def is_sequence_within(seq, target):
    return any(seq==target[i:i+len(seq)] for i in range(len(target)+1-len(seq)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
def is_subset(key, tup):
    for i in range(len(tup) - len(key) + 1):
        if key == tup[i : i + l]:
            return True
    return False
```

Or in a shorter way:

```
def is_subset(key, tup):
    return any(key == tup[i:i + len(key)] for i in range(len(tup) - len(key) + 1))
```

**Output:**

```
print is_subset((1, 2), (1, 2, 3)) # True
print is_subset((1, 3), (1, 2, 3)) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick would be to rely on substring search (that is quite optimized in Python)

```
def is_sequence_within(needle, haystack):
    if len(needle) == 0:
        return True
    return ("," + ",".join(map(str, needle)) + "," in
            "," + ",".join(map(str, haystack)) + ",")
```

if this is doable and/or efficient or not depends on how big are the tuples and what is the content.

Of course if you also search the same sequence for many subsequences then caching the haystack string would be much better.